# How to insert in a table according to two temp tables without a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two temp tables like this:

```
declare @Tbl_A table
(
 Id int
)

declare @Tbl_b table
(
 Seat nchar(1)
)
```

Sample data:

```
Tbl_A     Tbl_B    

10         A        
11         B        
12         C
```

I want to insert that data into a table `Tbl_C` according to first and second temp tables:

```
Tbl_C
(
  Id int,  
  Seat nchar(1)
)
```

Resulting data:

```
Id  Seat
10   A
10   B
10   C
11   A
11   B
11   C
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_C
    SELECT Id, Seat FROM @Tbl_A CROSS JOIN @Tbl_B

SELECT * FROM Tbl_C ORDER BY Id, Seat
```

Comment: I'm lazy and use a comma rather than the keywords CROSS JOIN